# Is there a cli way to determine all the binaries/packages a gradle multi project built?

Tags: gradle

I've got some jenkins code that wraps around gradle builds to handle artifact publish/promotion that happens outside of gradle.

At present, we use something like `buildGradle(def targetList, def publicationGlobs)` and use glob search to collect the artifacts.

Is there a way I can get gradle to report its built binaries that need to be published and their locations - especially when in a multi-project gradle build?

I have some 5k repositories and a heterogenous environment of gradle project approaches and gradle versions.  So I'm looking for a simple way to determine this would having to touch 100s or 1000s of projects.

Comment: Have you tried `./gradlew assemble --dry-run | grep jar`? 
You may want to change the grep pattern to match your binaries/packages.

Comment: that an interesting idea but unless I shift into debug I won't get much.  I think this may not be a solvable problem and that only the authors can know which jars should be part of publication vs not